# How to enable automatic transaction scoping on SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I'm used to work with tools like [Toad](http://www.toadsoft.com/toad_oracle.htm) or [PL/Sql Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) for Oracle and every SQL statement I run on the query window runs automatically under a trasaction scope. So, if my SQL statement is not correct, or even if I miss something on the SQL script I can rollback only by clicking on a button at the UI. If everything worked as expected, I can click on another button for commiting the current transaction.
On those tools I mentioned, I don't need to write SQL statements for begin, commit or rollback a transaction. Every SQL statement has an implicit transaction associated with.

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality on SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to set "Implict Transactions" in [tools..options..query execution](http://blog.techdreams.org/2007/11/implicit-transactions-onoff-sql-server.html)

To enable COMMIT or ROLLBACK, I can only think of using the [CTRL+number shortcuts](http://pentonizer.com/sql-server/ssms-custom-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Comment: I suggest reading the [documentation for `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx)