# SQL Server Management Studio Transaction and Variable

Tags: t-sql, ssms

In SSMS 2012, after setting `Options > Query Execution > ANSI > SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`, cf [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047676/how-to-enable-automatic-transaction-scoping-on-sql-server-management-studio)

I have the following code in a query window:

```
begin transaction 
    select @@TRANCOUNT
    begin
    declare @someNumber int; set @someNumber = 1; 
    print @someNumber;
    end
rollback
```

When I select the whole block and press `Execute`, I see the expected result, i.e. 1.

However, when I select the first 4 lines and execute, then select line 5, i.e. `print @someNumber;`, I got the following message:

> *Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1*
>   *Must declare the scalar variable "@someNumber".*

What is exactly the scope of the variable?

I'm baffled. Can someone shed any light or point me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [variable is scoped *per batch*.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927%28SQL.105%29.aspx)

> The scope of a local variable is the batch in which it is declared.

Each press of "Execute" is a batch. So, for the 2nd run, it isn't declared

What are doing with 2 runs is this

```
--start of batch 1
    begin transaction 
        select @@TRANCOUNT
        begin
        declare @someNumber int; set @someNumber = 1; 
--end of batch 1
        GO --separate batch after this
--start of batch 2
        print @someNumber;
        end
    rollback
--end of batch 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer and the helpful link! I want to set a variable to be used in multiple batches and I want inspect along the way. Can I change the behaviour of the "Execute"? Do I need to debug?

Comment: use a temporary table (one row, one column) to persist it

Comment: Thanks! I might end up writing a little .NET stored procedure to implement a map or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, a variable lives for the duration of the execution.

If you execute the declaration only, it dies when the execution ends.

If you then execute the print statement of the variable, it was not declared within this execution so it does not exists.