# SQL Management Studio - avoiding automatic commit

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I tried to search for a previous answer but the most similar is on a completely different question.

On TOAD for Oracle when I press F5 on an update I still have to choose if I want to commit or rollback.

On SSMS the commit is automatic.

Can I configure it to the need for an explicit commit?

EDIT

I've found that my question has got an exact response here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748818/196210

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable automatic transaction scoping on SQL Server Management Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047676/how-to-enable-automatic-transaction-scoping-on-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: SSMS-Tools-Options: [set implicit transactions](http://tinyurl.com/o3glaku) (image inside)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: please answer so that I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`set implicit transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) in SQL-Server Managemenet Studio. Therefore you have to change the default option from `off` to `on` here:

- Tools
- Options
- Query Execution
- SQL Server
- ANSI
- SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS

Here is an image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put `BEGIN TRANSACTION` at the top of your script.

Or use `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` (courtesy of [How do you set autocommit in an SQL Server session?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1090240/16391))